# Matching column names with row names

Tags: oracle, pivot, transpose

I have table1 with 366 columns name field1, field2.....field200. Each column has data in it pertaining to specific ids and dates.

I have another table2 with two columns name field_name and field_description. The column, field_name has rows field1,field2....field366 and it have the description pertaining to that field. How can I link the column name from table1 to get the data from those columns with the row name from table2 to get the description for each column in table1 for specifics ids in oracle?

```
table1
date        id   field1  field2   field3...
06-sept-17  001   yes    not bill  no


table2 
field_name field_description
field1     employee
field2     Parking_billed
field3     fee_paid
```

Comment: Are you using PL/SQL or just plane SQL?

Comment: Hi,  I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Hi K.O. can you please specify what is the desired output with an example using same data you have used in the question? e.g. is it **id 001 employee yes Parking_billed not bill fee_paid yes bold** ? ( I don't know how to format here and have written here the column heading and the data of it together). Thanks.